# How many "the"'s are needed in the phrase "the A of the B of the C ..."?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Here's an example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem):

> Statement: ... Suppose a function g ... has the set of discontinuity points D_g ...
>
> Proof: By (*the*) definition of *the* continuity of *the* function g(·), ...

(The first "the" is not used in the original text.)

Roughly speaking, the "continuity" has been specified in the previous context and differs slightly from the default meaning (on different "domain"). Its definition is the general one (indicating how it behaves in the specified domain) and is assumed to be known to the reader.

Comment: Does the function f have a different definition of continuity from the normal definition? Otherwise perhaps: Because the function f is continuous we can use the definition of continuity to show that ...

Comment: It varies. The palace of the king of the Netherlands, a box of cream of tartar, the fragrance of lily of the valley, a painting of the head of a man, etc.

Comment: @Peter, I've updated the context.

Comment: How was the continuity specified?  Is it assumed?  Was it proven?  Is it axiomatic?  Does function _f_'s continuity have a different definition from some other function's continuity, or are you writing about the definition of continuity itself?  Depending on your answers to these and other related questions, there may be other problems with this sentence aside from the inclusion or omission of articles.  In other words, the added context does not seem to be sufficient.

Comment: @phoog, I've updated with more details。

Comment: Thanks.  I should probably bow out at this point because I'm not familiar with the style, but I would tend to prefer "by the definition of the continuity of the function."  One might omit the first "the" because of the common phrase "by definition," as in "a set is by definition unordered."  Still, if referring to a specific definition, I'd likely say "by the definition of _set_." In this case, though, I wonder whether the discontinuity points of _g_ are better characterized as "by assumption" rather than "by definition."

Comment: @phoog, thank you. This proof utilizes a property of continuity rather than the assumption about discontinuity points. In this context, it may effectively be equivalent to stating "Let g be a continuous function. ... By ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By the definition of the continuity of the function *g(.)*

To me that is awkward, not because of the chained "*the*"s but because of the chained "*of*"s. The chain suggests to me that the definition you are talking of applies only to the function *g(.)*, even though I know better.

It is common to shorten "the function *g(.)*" to "function *g(.)*", or even to just "*g(.)*". It is also common to refer to "the definition of continuity". The phrase

> by the definition of continuity of function *g(.)*

drops both "*the*"s; it is as good as your original, but to me it is still awkward because of the "*of*"s.

I would prefer to rephrase the second "*of*". You would leave out the middle "*the*" because "definition of continuity" is standard, but the third, and the word "*function*", are optional.

> By the definition of continuity applied to (the) (function) *g(.)* ...

Alternatively you could punctuate with parentheses

> By the definition of continuity (of function *g*) ...

Answer (score -1):

The definite article applies to the one and unique instance of its following concept.

Your quotation refers to:
*The* definition (implying that there is only one definition already known; if not already known you might omit “the” so as to imply that there is no unique definition of f but that you are about to define it)
of *the* continuity (see below)
of *the* function (referring to the one function previously mentioned or defined).

The validity of the second usage demands more thought:

If the function is continuous everywhere (across all of its domain, for example from minus infinity to plus infinity) there is only one continuity. If it is piecewise continuous (for example below or above zero, with a break at zero) you might omit the definite article so as to recognise that there is no unique continuity, perhaps leading on to a discussion of “the” part below zero or “the” part above zero, or even to discussion of the discontinuity at zero.

Hence, the last ‘the” is reasonably needed; the first and second depend on context and intention.

Comment: Thank you @Anton. I've updated the question.  If both the definition and the continuity are already known to the reader within the given context, then the first and second "the" should be remained, right?

Comment: Also, if for the sake of conciseness, can some "the" be omitted while still keeping the expression correct?

Comment: @yatse in many cases, (the) omission of a definite article is optional, but it frequently shows the writer to be a non-native speaker of English.  Without more context it's hard to say here.

Comment: It would helpful if the mute downvoter explained themselves so as to help the questioner understand the matter better. What is the point of downvoting without explanation?